# Can't start from scratch -- Brew and Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

My dev environment is hosed and I just want to start from zero. Any time I run `brew` or `gem`, I get this error message:

`` /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' ``

Can anyone help me here? I'm at my wit's end. I just want to blow it all away and reinstall it.

Comment: Personally I'd use a version manager and do nothing to touch OS X's own Rubies.

Comment: I would too. I was, in fact. Why is it looking at my system ruby, and not rvm's?

Comment: Because your path is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's your local ruby version that comes packaged with osx.  There's no reason to remove that, you just need to use something like rvm or rbenv which will install all your gem dependencies according to the ruby version you're working in.

Most likely you've got a compatibility issue withe a gem and ruby 2.0.0.  I personally use rvm so I'd do this:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Checkout the install guide [here](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)